# input.setfocus is not a function in Ionic and Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

On clicking a field I want it to come on top of my mobile keyboard. In order to do that, I am trying with the following code but getting error.

**Home.html** code as follows:

```
  <div *ngIf="this.primary">
    <textarea style="background-color:#f5f8fa;border:none;width:80%;margin-left:25px;" autosize #input  (click)="focusInput(input)" (input)= "charvl()" placeholder="Enter description.." name="taskdesc" [(ngModel)]="taskdesc"></textarea>
  </div>
```

**Home.ts** code as follows:

```
  focusInput(input) 
  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      input.setFocus();
    },150);


    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
    console.log("focus");
    }
```

When I click on the field, I see this error on my console.

> input.setfocus is not a function

Comment: are you using @ViewChild

Comment: no, i am simply fowwing this tutorial  https://mhartington.io/post/setting-input-focus/

Answer (score 0):

Try with @ViewChild

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class PageName {

  @ViewChild('input') myInput;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

    focusInput()  // no need to pass the input as parameter we are accessing the html element using @ViewChild
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.myInput.setFocus();
    },150);

    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
    console.log("focus");
  }  
}
```

Comment: i was using `textarea` and not `ion-textarea` . it worked , but when i am trying the same thing on `ion-searchbar`, there is no error but it is not coming on top

Comment: Yes i missed it you need to use ion-textarea and i have not used it for searchbar yet but try  using this @ViewChild('searchbar') searchbar: Searchbar; and import { Searchbar } from 'ionic-angular';